# Dell T420: can I replace the original non-redundant power supply with two redundant ones?

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell, power-supply-unit

A Dell T420 bought in 2015 was originally configured with the single 550W non-redundant power supply.  Replacement parts are cheap these days, and I'd like to replace the single P/S with dual redundant power supplies. Can I simply pull out the existing P/S and replace it with two others, or is there a motherboard (or other) configuration issue that prevents a T420 originally built with the non-redundant P/S to accept redundant ones?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation.  You cannot just use the two ps.  There is a kit with a couple of boards and the ps.  Super easy to convert with one caveat.  The T420 has to have a backplane for the hdd’s.  The redundant ps power distributor board is incompatible with wired hdd’s.